# Interactively kill process using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-v5.1

How can an interactive method for killing process in powershell be created?

Kill process preferably in a form using input field to find and kill the processes desired.

Comment: you can use `Get-Process` to get the list of processes, filter out any that you want to hide, feed the remaining items to `Out-Gridview` with `-OutputMode Single` and a useful msg to the user, and - finally - use the output from that to kill the process. [*grin*]

Comment: there is no way on ogv to kill the process from that point

Comment: um, er, what? [*grin*] the output of the O-GV call will be one item that can be used with the desired next cmdlet - such as `Stop-Process`.

Comment: i created that script as you suggested and while it does kill a process, selecting the process is not an interactive procedure and so it doesn't address the actual question.

Comment: your definition is apparently very different from mine. [*grin*] my method presents a list, allows one to choose one item, and then stops it. that seems to be interactive to me ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best I could come up with

```bsh
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') | Out-Null
$killme = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Enter complete or portion of process name', 'Process Name', "")


Get-Process  | Where-Object ProcessName -Like "*$killme*" | kill -confirm -Force -PassThru
```